# Python Align two images according to specified co-ordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images from two different imaging hardware. I need to align them to each other creating a composite of both pictures. First image serves as background as it has better resolution and second picture needs to be an overlay with low opacity so the colorful points on the second picture are visible. For this I specify at least 3 points on image1 and corresponding 3 points on image2.

Image1:

[image: Image1]

Image2:

[image: Image2]

Desired Output must look something like this:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

It's a calibration problem and you should use `findHomography` command from opencv.

It takes two sets of point which the first set is the pixel coordinates of the red dots in the second image (the colorful one) and the second set must be the coordinates of those red dots in the first image.

The output of this command is 3*3 matrix which is the map you need. Give this matrix and the second image to opencv's `warpPerspective` command and this will give you the target image which you can overlay with the original image.

Of course `findHomography` needs more than 3 dots for a good result (8 points is good), but it still works with 3 dots.

Comment: I have already tried using `findHomography` . It gives a lot of false positives and outputs nonsense image as the quality of colorful image is very bad. Do you reckon `affineTransformation` would be useful?

Comment: You could use getAffineTransform instead of findHomography but probably that too gives you bad results because the nature of your mapping is not Affine. Besides the quality of your mapping is completely independent from the image's quality! you just need to add some ground truth points between two images (more than 3).

Comment: I will try that and let you know, thank you for your efforts anyway!

Comment: sadly it did not work out as expected, these are my modified input images  and the matching result at the end https://imgur.com/a/9OgAKkA, my code to align was: https://pastebin.com/Sbdm7KWE

Comment: @JackSparrow You can also use feature point extraction method like sift or surf to find matched points between the two images then apply findhomography on the matched points. Of course you need to enhance the second image before feature extraction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, would you be kind enough to give me an example? I am a newbie in OpenCV. How exactly would I need to enhance the image?

Comment: @JackSparrow Sorry image enhancement is a broad disscussion and it's not just some lines of commands. You have to search about the keywords I mentioned (and sift, surf,...) and read a little more, then you will find the way.